# Form Validation, problems with passing of argument and page redirection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

So I'm creating this form validator with PHP and jQuery.
The PHP code will check through the form and then return an array with fields that contain errors. Example: {"email":1,"password":1}

But now I have concerns regarding if no errors were to be found. The problem here is that I've included "return false" in the end of the code to prevent page redirection. I've read that this is bad code practice but not found another way that works as intended.

The second problem is how to pass the o-array into the $('input').each function. Right now it will say that all forms are valid since nothing was passed. If I use $.post instead of $.ajax this scope problem doesn't appear for some reason.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $('#register').submit(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function(o) {
                console.log(o);
                $('input').each(function() {
                    var msgId = o[$(this).attr('name')];
                    console.log(o[$(this).attr('name')]);

                    if (msgId > 0) {
                        $('#listError').css('visibility', 'visible');
                        $('#listError').append('<li>' + $(this).nextAll('span.msg').eq(msgId - 1).text() + '</li>');
                        $(this).addClass('invalid');
                    } else if (msgId != 0) {
                        $(this).addClass('valid');
                    }
                    $('#listError').append('</ul>');
                })
            }
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach. You are submitting a form that you really don't want to submit and then prevent it from being submitted. What exactly is the problem with passed value `o`?

Answer (score 0):

Fist, why are you submitting a form when you really don't want to?! Use a button instead and make the AJAX request from its click handler.

```
$('#registerButton').click(function() {
    var form = $('#register')

    var data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax(...);
});
```

"The second problem is how to pass the o-array into the $('input').each"

What is the problem here? If you have an `each()` inside a success callback, you can use the `data` parameter that is passed to the callback (or `o` in your case) in that each().

Comment: Maybe I missed something but I didn't get this approach to do any difference. The problem with o is that it doesn't seem to exist inside the each-function. Every value in the array shows up as 'undefined' in the log.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(function() {

    $('#submit_button_id').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var ret = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(o) {
                console.log(o);
                $('input').each(function() {
                    var msgId = o[$(this).attr('name')];
                    console.log(o[$(this).attr('name')]);

                    if (msgId > 0) 
                        ret = false;
                        $('#listError').css('visibility', 'visible');
                        $('#listError').append('<li>' + $(this).nextAll('span.msg').eq(msgId - 1).text() + '</li>');
                        $(this).addClass('invalid');
                    } else if (msgId != 0) {
                        $(this).addClass('valid');
                    }
                    $('#listError').append('</ul>');
                })
            }
        }, 'json');

        if(ret==true){
            $('#register').submit();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This way the submit handler will always return true thus submit the form. You are missing the point of asynchronous execution. The main execution thread will continue after the end of the `$.ajax();` statement is reached and the success callback will execute at a later time so it will _not_ have a chance to change the `ret` variable before the submit callback returns it.

Comment: I see, you're absolutely right, I've ammended the code with async: false;

Comment: I missed that.. but that's a _very_ bad way of doing this except for a few exception with a good reason.

Comment: Have you tried $('#submit_button_id').click(function(){.... Then trigger $('#register').submit() if it clears validation (answer ammended)